# Which Game of Thrones cast members are shown in this photo from a Seville, Spain soccer match?

Tags: game-of-thrones, actor-identification

[image: Photo of Game of Thrones cast at a soccer match in Seville, Spain]

This photo was taken this evening in Seville, Spain, into Sanchez Pizjuán Stadium. Obviously the people in it are from the cast of "Game of thrones" but I can't identify all of them (not a very good photo, I'm afraid).

Can you help me?

Comment: *"I can't identify all of them"* Which ones **can** you name? Because when you say *"Can you help me?"* the 'help' seems to imply naming them all. Is this for some competition?

Comment: @AndrewThompson It's not for a competition. It's just for helping a person who was there and is not used to the series. Just out of curiosity. I can identify six of them, I think, but they are really easy and I think it's better to leave them for an answer.

Comment: By the way, here are Jaime Lanister and Euron Greyjoy: http://i65.tinypic.com/2f09dl1.jpg

Comment: No doubt you'll see more images and stories about this once more news hounds get wind of it.

Comment: I edited the title so that it focuses more on the question and sounds less like a challenge. Feel free to rollback if the edit goes too far.

Comment: @Adamant It's fine, thanks. I didn't mean to pose a challenge, but when you're using a language which is not your native one is hard to notice some implications.

Comment: This should have the "Spoiler" warning, don't you think ?

Comment: You say it's a photo, but it doesn't look like a photo. It looks like 5 photos.

Comment: @MrLister Well, it looks like a docen photos and a video now. ;)

Comment: @Bebs I was considering the spoiler warning, but I'm not  sure if it's spoiler enough to know that "Game of thrones" is being located at half docen places in Spain. Seville's location suggest a certain kingdom in Westeros, but very near Seville was the location of Mereen and a hour by car was "Volantis". Dothraki sea was also located in Andalusia.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<sub>I should preface this by saying that the following *may* contain spoilers, in that knowing the location of shooting, and knowing that certain actors were present in that location, you *may* be spoiled as to who appears where. Just sayin'.</sub>

---

That is a photo from a recent football match from the [Sevilla Fútbol Club](http://www.sevillafc.es/) when they were up against [FC Barcelona](https://www.fcbarcelona.com/) about [1 hour ago](http://www.espnfc.com.au/report?gameId=458976). [Tweeted by the official Sevilla twitter account](https://twitter.com/SevillaFC/status/795347315162828800).

The match was highlighted by the appearance of the *[Game of Thrones](http://www.hbo.com/game-of-thrones)* cast (who were currently filming scenes in Seville for season 7 of the show) who attended the match in support of Seville.

---

Although **Mike** has most of the cast covered [in his answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/144679/21267), here's what he missed:
<sub>[from left to right - the ones with a "*" were covered by Mike's answer]</sub>

1. **Pilou Asbæk** (plays Euron Greyjoy)

   [image: https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/t31.0-8/14976642_10154856922851833_2515974276792997743_o.jpg]
2. **Alfie Allen*** (plays Theon Greyjoy)

   [image: https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/t31.0-8/14976918_10154856919581833_5408394963753353661_o.jpg]
3. **Emilia Clarke*** (Mhysa)

   [image: https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/t31.0-8/14976488_10154856919371833_3602546455928362_o.jpg]
4. definitely **Anton Lesser** (plays Qyburn)

   [image: https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/t31.0-8/14940193_10154856921901833_4503978514086473157_o.jpg]
5. **David Benioff*** (showrunner)

   [image: https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/t31.0-8/14991162_10154856921006833_4883727512324884691_o.jpg]
6. definitely **Conleth Hill** (plays Varys)

   [image: https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/t31.0-8/15000088_10154856923146833_1202925072504889533_o.jpg]
7. **Peter Dinklage*** (plays Tyrion Lannister)

   [image: https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/t31.0-8/14976520_10154856920186833_6480488255358921898_o.jpg]
8. **Hafþór (Thor) Júlíus Björnsson*** (plays Gregor Clegane / The Mountain)

   [image: https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/t31.0-8/14999985_10154856920676833_2106810368685644038_o.jpg]

   Yes, they spelled his name wrong! awks.
9. **D. B. Weiss*** (showrunner)

   [image: https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/t31.0-8/15025126_10154856921806833_635149913415301939_o.jpg]
10. **Iain Glen*** (plays Jorah Mormont)

    [image: https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/t31.0-8/14976921_10154856920756833_6523191969674976787_o.jpg]
11. **Gwendoline Christie*** (plays Brienne of Tarth)

    [image: https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/t31.0-8/14976478_10154856923486833_7489218146542239909_o.jpg]
12. **Liam Cunningham*** (plays Davos Seaworth)

    [image: https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/t31.0-8/14990998_10154856922641833_7595660845875466897_o.jpg]

---

For anyone who's interested, the match ended with the following result:

[image: Image of final soccer match, Sevilla VS Barcelona, Sevilla lost 1, nil.]

<sup>[[src]](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CwnBbkeXAAESVYe.jpg)</sup>

Here's a nice [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6XS0K5CvKaw) of the cast members entering their VIP watching area, where you can see the actors a little bit more clearly:

Answer (score 4):

From left to right, they are:

- Pilou Asbæk (Euron Greyjoy)
- Alfie Allen (Theon Greyjoy)
- Emilia Clarke (Danaerys Targaryen)
- *possibly* Anton Lesser (Qyburn)
- David Benioff (showrunner)
- *possibly* Conleth Hill (Varys)
- Peter Dinklage (Tyrion Lannister)
- Hafþór Júlíus Björnsson (Gregor Clegane, Season 4+)
- D. B. Weiss (showrunner)
- Iain Glen (Jorah Mormont)
- Gwendoline Christie (Brienne of Tarth)
- Liam Cunningham (Davos Seaworth)

Comment: chap on the far left is Pilou Asbæk (plays Euron Greyjoy)